# Cannot download files/images from uploads folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webclient

i need to download images that i stored in folder in `asp.net` web application name as `uploads`

i got a function that should download this as

```
private void downloadAnImage(string strImage)
{
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strImage);
    Response.TransmitFile(strImage);
    Response.End();
}
```

and i call this function from `link button` as

```
protected void lnkDwnSlc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["slc_filepath"] != null)
    {                 
         string path = Server.MapPath(Session["slc_filepath"].ToString());
         downloadAnImage(path);
    }
}
```

where `Session["slc_filepath"]` is path stored in `session`

but after running this code file/image is not downloading and I got no error about why file is not downloading. And I checked file path by using `breakpoint` , it is correct,

I search a lot form google but i can't understand where I missed something.

**EDIT:**
on page load event i pull records from table there i saved path of file and in session i store it like

```
Session["slc_filepath"] = dt.Rows[0]["UploadSLC"].ToString();
```

where `UploadSLC` is column name of table where i store path of image
and in database string is looking as

```
~\uploads\ab071770-473a-4e1a-8cfc-addeccf565d5.jpg
```

Comment: Also share how are you assigning the path in session that will be more helpful.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal, please see my edit

Comment: insert Response.Flush() before Response.End

Comment: @jomsk1e, i did acording to your sugg but not working , same result do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer after a long searching but a hint i got is from my junior in my team i really appreciate it, i just added

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.lnkDwnSlc);
```

in `pageLoad` event because i am using update panel and script manager in my aspx page and bootstrap for design so it stopped functionality

after doing so it works like a charm,

thanks all of your efforts and support,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void downloadAnImage(string strImage)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strImage);
    Response.TransmitFile(strImage);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Happy to help you!

Comment: Are you using ajax panels to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to troubleshoot the issue where it came from.

1. Try a hardcoded path (to make sure, you are passing the correct path)

   ```
   //try forward or back slash, make sure the file exists
   string path = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/ab071770-473a-4e1a-8cfc-addeccf565d5.jpg");
   ```
2. Try this:

   ```
   private void downloadAnImage(string strImage)
   {
       Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
       Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strImage);
       Response.TransmitFile(strImage);
       Response.Flush();
       Response.End();
   }
   ```
3. Make sure there's no javascript error that is being thrown on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your path of image while binding from database

like "~/Image/images.png ".

PFB of my snippet code you may supposed to get solution.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["slc_filepath"] = "~/Image/images.png";
        }

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath(Session["slc_filepath"].ToString());
        downloadAnImage(path);
    }

    private void downloadAnImage(string strImage)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strImage);
        Response.TransmitFile(strImage);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ashx Handler like this http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/asp-net/how-to-download-files-from-server-to-client-using-a-generic-handler/

Then send by ajax a window.Open to the new ashx.